# How to configure retry in AmazonS3EncryptionClient

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to create and use [AmazonS3EncryptionClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3EncryptionClient.html) for storing and retriving objects encrypted at client side from S3, however the APIs for creating an object of this type having manually configured retries is deprecated as per [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3EncryptionClient.html)

It is now recommended to use [AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder.html) instead to build the `AmazonS3EncryptionClient`.
However the builder documentation doesn't provide any API for adding clientConfiguration which had the retry strategy... it only has the CryptoConfiguration which doesn't seem to support retry configuration.

Is there any way we can set the retry policy on S3 in the client itself or do we need to manually implement it in our codebase ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using something like this

```
//Step 1: Create a clientBuilder first

AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEncryptionMaterials(new StaticEncryptionMaterialsProvider(encryptionMaterials))
        .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());

//Step 2: Create your custom client configuration for retry policy

    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    //clientConfiguration.setMaxErrorRetry(10);
    clientConfiguration.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(RetryPolicy.RetryCondition.NO_RETRY_CONDITION,
        RetryPolicy.BackoffStrategy.NO_DELAY, 10, true));

//Step3: set client Configuration in builder

    builder.setClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration);

//Step 4: build AWSEncryptionClient

    AmazonS3Encryption client = builder.build();
```

I wonder there could be an easier (simpler) way to do it. But it should solve your problem, I had used it.

Aws documentation is not always updated and it's a bit of pain to go into details whether all things provided are supported without any changes in AWS console.

I hope it helps. Cheers!!